# Application size with loading Apple MAP

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting, apple-maps

I am struggling with a problem that looks like simple but it is making the app run size to 30-35 MB. The app is ARC enabled. Here is the scenario.

1) I invoke a `UIViewcontroller` from within my method (the viewController instance is local to the method)& after pushing it to `NavigationController` I am setting the local instance as nil.

```
    btMapViewController *routeMap = [[btMapViewController alloc]init];
        [routeMap setSourcLocation:[txtsource text]];
        [routeMap setDestinationLocation:[txtDestination text]];
        [routeMap setNightFareOn:addNightCharge];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:routeMap animated:YES];
        routeMap = nil;
```

2) The newly pushed controller initializes a `MKMapView` & plot the routes on it. The app now runs on a memory of 35-40 MB which is 5 times more than what it was running before step 1.

```
@interface btMapViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) MKMapView *mapView;
@end
```

3) Now if I pop out the `UIViewcontroller` (the one loaded in step 1), the app runs on a memory of 30-34 MB.

I check the Memory trace, its clear. Then who is holding the memory ?

Is that the MKMap is the part of Interface Implementation is leading to this problem or shall I make it private to the `btMapViewController` class. ?

Comment: You can use Instruments to see which objects have been allocated and never released before and after you create your view controller. If you see objects that you don't expect to continue existing, you can look at the call stack for each allocation to finger the responsible code.