# iOS:Pushing to a mkmapview over and over causes memory leaks, what is the best course of action to prevent this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, mkmapview

I was wondering what is the best way to disable memory leaks for `MKMapView` for iOS when pushing to the `UIViewController`. I have to push to this `MKMapView` but by doing so it causes the map to jitter and eventually crashes. I am not sure what I can do to prevent this situation. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you pushing, and how do you go back from the map view before you push again?

Comment: I am loading mkmapview from start I go to another view controller and I push back. If I pop to the controller nothing goes wrong, but I need to push to the viewcontroller in this instance.

Comment: I am also running with this problem but could not see any leaks in the instrument. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419665/application-size-with-loading-apple-map)

Comment: You should never "push back" to something. That doesn't actually go back, it creates another instance. You should always pop when going backwards and push when gong forward.

Comment: Just pushing to an MKMapView shouldn't cause it to jitter and then crash. You need to provide more detail on your controller hierarchy, and how you're moving between controllers.

Comment: "what is the best way to disable memory leaks for MKMapView">?

Answer: Don't use it.